# Simulated key command not working since OS upgrade

Tags: applescript

I considered posting this to [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) but I thought it belonged here due to being mainly focused on code.

I have created a macro on my mac for switching spaces, and since upgrading to Sierra the following AppleScript is no longer working. Does anyone know if something has changed?

```
tell application "System Events" to key code 124 using control down
```

and

```
tell application "System Events" to key code 123 using control down
```

This is the output when running in terminal (note the `^[[1;5D`):

```
14:16 isaac@Isaac ~ $ osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to key code 123 using control down'
^[[1;5D14:18 isaac@Isaac ~ $ ;5D
```

And when running via AppleScript Editor, nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's a bug.

To simulate some global shortcut with the **Control** key, the command needs the **fn** key (a workaround for **Sierra**).

It's not possible to use the **fn** key with the AppleScript's `key code` command, but it's possible with the methods of the `Core Graphics` framework in a **Python** script.

---

Here's the script to simulate this shortcut --> (**Right Arrow + Control**), you can run the script in the **Terminal** (in a sh, bash or any similar shell)

```
/usr/bin/python -c 'import time; import Quartz.CoreGraphics as QCG; e = QCG.CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(None, 124, True); QCG.CGEventSetFlags(e, (QCG.kCGEventFlagMaskControl | QCG.kCGEventFlagMaskSecondaryFn)); QCG.CGEventPost(QCG.kCGHIDEventTap, e); time.sleep(0.1); QCG.CGEventSetType(e, QCG.kCGEventKeyUp); QCG.CGEventPost(QCG.kCGHIDEventTap, e)'
```

---

Here's an AppleScript to test in the "**Script Editor**" application:

```
--  For switching spaces, 124 = the Right Arrow key, use 123 for the Left Arrow key
do shell script "/usr/bin/python -c 'import time; import Quartz.CoreGraphics as QCG; e = QCG.CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(None, 124, True); QCG.CGEventSetFlags(e, (QCG.kCGEventFlagMaskControl | QCG.kCGEventFlagMaskSecondaryFn)); QCG.CGEventPost(QCG.kCGHIDEventTap, e); time.sleep(0.1); QCG.CGEventSetType(e, QCG.kCGEventKeyUp); QCG.CGEventPost(QCG.kCGHIDEventTap, e)'"
```

Comment: You legend... I thought something was up

Comment: I tried your solution jackjr300 but it wouldn't work for me. Does this still work in the latest version of OS X?

Comment: The bug may be resolved, I don't know because I have not installed high Sierra yet. Try to remove `| QCG.kCGEventFlagMaskSecondaryFn` in the script.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your key codes match the keyboard shortcuts in system preferences.  Here are my keyboard shortcuts in system preferences and they do coincide correctly with my AppleScript commands.

[image]

```
tell application "System Events"
    key code 18 using (control down) -- Desktop 1
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    key code 19 using (control down) -- Desktop 2
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    key code 20 using (control down) -- Desktop 3
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    key code 21 using (control down) -- Desktop 4
end tell
```

These function correctly for me in the latest version of Sierra.

Comment: it's odd, these keys seem to work... by not the ctrl + left or ctrl + right commands